# Function undefined inside a component

Tags: reactjs

im trying reactjs and i got an undefined and i dont kow why.
The code is really simple but maybe i didnt get something ?!

```
  isMailValid(mail) {
    const valid_mail = RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?");
    console.log("res => " + valid_mail.test(mail));
    return valid_mail.test(mail);
  }

  isMailOk() {
    var res = this.isMailValid(this.state.mail)
    if (res === true)
      return (<p class="false">invalid mail</p>);
    return (<p class="good">Mail Ok</p>); 
  }
```

I got 'isMailValid' is not defined  no-undef.
Thx for help

Comment: Can you post your whole class?

Comment: `valid_mail` is a string. it doesn't have `test`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: To fix your code, it needs to be `const valid_mail =  RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?");`

Comment: thanks it solves a problem but i cant get what i want. there is no message under the input. (I edit the code)

Answer (score 1):

The function is undefined because it is not in the same scope as the function calling it. To access it you'll have to prefix the call with `this.` to tell React where to find the function.

```
isMailOk() {
    if (this.isMailValid(this.state.mail) === true)
      return (<p class="false">Mail invalid</p>);
    return (<p class="good">Mail Ok</p>); 
  }
```

You'll also have to bind your custom function to `this`. You can do that by placing `this.isMailOk = this.isMailOk.bind(this);` in the constructor. You'll have to do that with both of your custom functions. Functions such as `render` don't require being bound to this because they are inherited when you extend your class from `React.Component`. You can read more about binding to `this` [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Comment: I'd encourage reading through the docs for binding functions to the class. You can also do it through the arrow syntax (`=>`). If you're using create-react-app, the support is out of the box. You don't have to `bind` in the constructor if your functions use the arrow syntax.